# How to setup MetricBalancingThresholds and MetricActivityThresholds on Azure Service Fabric cluster?

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I have a Service Fabric cluster with 7 nodes.
I am using Microsoft Azure Service Fabric version 8.2.1571.9590.

The problem is, the cluster is not balanced by CPU nor Memory usage.
It is balanced by the number of PrimaryCount, ReplicaCount and similar metrics, but not by CPU or Memory usage.
The result is, because some of our services are heavy spenders of CPU/RAM ("noisy neighbour" issue), they consume more resources, starving other services in the process.

I know I can set MetricBalancingThresholds and MetricActivityThresholds for our cluster, but don't know metrics names.

I figured based on article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-resource-manager-balancing
that I can setup MetricBalancingThresholds and MetricActivityThresholds
(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-fabric-settings)

I know that we can set those values in Azure portal / Service fabric resource / Custom fabric settings.
The problem is, I don't know what parameter names, or metrics names to use to set thresholds on CPU and Memory.

The documentation says: "PropertyGroup", but I don't know what are possible values here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-fabric-settings#metricactivitythresholds

Earlier CpuPercentageNodeCapacity and MemoryPercentageNodeCapacity were used in PlacementAndLoadBalancing section, tho

se were straightforward, but it seems they are deprecated.